# Resultado com registros repetidos

Tags: mysql, query

Boa tarde!
Estou fazendo uma consulta, mas o resultado está trazendo ocorrências repetidas. há algum comando para que a consulta somente traga um registro de cada coluna?

segue script:

```
SELECT *
FROM HIS_LOTPES A, his_afasta c, FERIAS D, PESSOAL P
WHERE A.HLOT_PESS_CD_MAT = c.hafa_pess_cd_mat(+)
AND A.HLOT_PESS_CD_MAT = D.FERI_PESS_CD_MAT(+)
AND P.PESS_CD_MAT = D.FERI_PESS_CD_MAT(+)
and a.hlot_dt_inicio <> c.hafa_dt_inicial(+)
and a.hlot_dt_saida <> c.hafa_dt_final(+)
and a.hlot_dt_inicio < feri_dt_inicio(+)
and a.hlot_uorg_cd_ent = '2'
and a.hlot_uorg_ufed_sg = 'DF'
and a.hlot_uorg_cd_org = '1'
and a.hlot_uorg_cd_gab = '101'
and a.hlot_uorg_cd_dep = '2'
and a.hlot_uorg_cd_div = '0'
and a.hlot_uorg_cd_set = '1'
and a.hlot_uorg_cd_sec = '1'
AND A.HLOT_DT_INICIO > '01/01/2015'
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Você já tentou usar o `distinct`? Select  distinct * from HIS_LOTPES...

Comment: Eu acho que já vi uma pergunta identica esses dias, tenho impressão que essa é uma duplicata. O problema era exatamente um Join com uma relação N:N, provavelmente o mesmo que ocorre daqui. Aliás, Joins implícitos montados com WHERE geralmente ficam mais difíceis de se ler, analisar e ajustar, sugeriria fazer explícito, [escolhendo os tipos certos de junção de acordo com o resultado desejado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode esta utilizando a opção distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tabela
```

Porém será agrupado se a linha toda for igual, caso uma coluna seja diferente irá trazer (pois se uma coluna é diferente o registro não é igual).